# In Stata, how do I modify axes of dot chart?

Tags: graph, stata

I'm trying to create a dot chart in Stata, splitting it into two categories

Running a chunk of code:

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
drop if race == 3
graph dot (mean) wage, over(occ) by(race)
```

Creates such output:

[image]

So far so good but I'd like to remove labels of Y axis from the right graph to give the data some more space.

The only way I've been able to do that was to manually edit graph and hide the axis label object:

[image]

Is there a way to do it programmatically? I do know I could use one more `over()` but in some graphs of mine that is already taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution is buried in `help bystyle` and `help by_option`. However, I can't get it to work with your example (I'm on Stata 12). But the description is clear. For example:

> A bystyle determines the overall look of the combined graphs,
>   including
>
> 1. whether the individual graphs have their own axes and labels or if instead the axes and labels are shared across graphs arrayed in the
>      same row and/or in the same column;
>
> ...
>
> There are options that let you control each of the above attributes --
>   see [G-3] by_option --

And also

> iyaxes and ixaxes (and noiyaxes and noixaxes) specify whether the y axes and x axes are 
>   to be displayed with each graph.  The default
>   with most styles and
>      schemes is to place y axes on the leftmost graph of each row and to place x axes on 
>   the bottommost graph of each column.  The y and
>   x axes include the
>           default ticks and labels but exclude the axes titles.

If for some reason that doesn't work out, something like

```
sysuse nlsw88, clear
drop if race == 3

graph dot (mean) wage, over(occ) by(race)
gr_edit .plotregion1.grpaxis[2].draw_view.setstyle, style(no)
```

does (but I don't really like the approach). You can mess with at least the axis number `[#]` to do a bit of customization. I guess recording changes in the graphical editor and then recycling the corresponding code, may be one way out of difficult situations.

Comment: Thank you Roberto - `gr_edit` did the trick. Wasn't aware you that 'recording' can be saved and used as text file!

Comment: You're welcome. Did you try any variant of `graph dot (mean) wage, over(occ) by(race, noiyaxes noiylabels)`? This produces no errors for me, but the graph is not how I expect it. Don't know if my expectations are just fantasy. Reading the help files, I thought that would solve the issue. Maybe it has something to do with my graph settings...

Comment: `noiyaxes noiylabels` doesn't seem to have an effect for me either (I'm on Stata 13) - double labels persist :/